# eclipse plugin issue with welcome screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have written a eclipse plugin which will customize the eclipse welcome screen.
Below is the xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <introContent>  
>   <extensionContent id="comregistrationplugin-introExtension"
> style="css/sample.css" name="Sample Extension" path="overview/@">
>       <group style-id="content-group"
> id="comregistrationplugin-introLink-group">
>               <link label="Registration/Signup" url="" id="comregistrationplugin-introLink" style-id="content-link">
>                   <text>Click here to login.</text>
>               </link>
>           </group>    </extensionContent> </introContent>
```

Once I click on the link, it opens up the url specified on the link in the web browser.
The url that I use is a sso url which will open up a login page . Once the user provides the email address the user will be logged in and and the api will return a response.
I need a way to capture the response without showing the response on the users browser. For ex, once the response is received I need a way to capture the response in the plugin and show a generic success message on the users browser. 
Or is there a way to read the cookie once the login succeeds ?

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to find the corresponding editor, and grovel through it to find the `Browser` and install your own listener.  But you might be better off creating your own browser instance, either through a dialog or as a separate editor, so you can control the setup.  I implemented something like this for [the Eclipse User Storage Service](https://git.eclipse.org/c/usssdk/org.eclipse.usssdk.git/tree/org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth/src/org/eclipse/userstorage/internal/oauth/ui/LoginDialog.java).